# can't run my first python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to google app engine coding can't view my hello-world app in localhost.when run the app in google app engine launcher it is appear like this [image]

I can't find out  the error .i need a little help...... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you configured the path to python27 in GAE's Preference options? In Launcher go to Edit -> Preferences and set Python Path to match your python 27 path.

Answer (score 3):

Google App Engine is not designed to be run with Python 3.x - you'll need to install Python 2.7 instead.

Comment: but the same.i re install python27 same but in console says only"2013-08-24 23:13:42 (Process exited with code 1)"